# Converting MySQL query to Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I am trying to convert following MySQL query to Hive

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT
    departments.dept_name,
    dept_emp.dept_no,
    gender,
    (count(*)/(select count(*) from employees)) AS Sex
FROM 
    employees,
    dept_emp,departments
WHERE 
    dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
    AND dept_emp.emp_no =  employees.emp_no
GROUP BY 
    dept_emp.dept_no, 
    departments.dept_name,
    gender
ORDER BY 
    dept_emp.dept_no;
```

**Hive Query**

```
WITH 
    q1 as (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT FROM employees),
    q2 as (SELECT gender,COUNT(*) as gender_count FROM employees GROUP BY gender)
SELECT 
    departments.dept_name,
    dept_emp.dept_no,
    gender,
    gender_count/TOTAL_COUNT As Sex 
FROM 
    q1,
    q2,
    dept_emp,
    departments
WHERE 
    dept_emp.dept_no = departments.dept_no
    AND dept_emp.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
GROUP BY 
    dept_emp.dept_no, 
    departments.dept_name,
    q2.gender
ORDER BY 
    dept_emp.dept_no;
```

But I am getting error

> SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 3:53 Expression not in `GROUP BY` key : `TOTAL_COUNT`

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the error on missing non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, the logic in your new query seems different than the one in the legacy query (for example : subquery `q2` computes something new... and has no join condition with other tables).

Hive does not support subqueries in the `SELECT` clause, but it [does allow them in  `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries). I would simply move the inline subquery to the `FROM` clause. Since it returns only one record, that would be a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    d.dept_name,
    de.dept_no,
    e.gender,
    (count(*)/x.cnt) AS Sex
FROM 
    employees e
    INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON de.emp_no =  e.emp_no
    INNER JOIN departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM employees) x
GROUP BY 
    de.dept_no, 
    d.dept_name,
    e.gender
ORDER BY 
    de.dept_no;
```

NB1: always use *explicit*, standard `JOIN`s instead of old-shool, *implicit* `JOIN`s; I modified the query accordingly (and also added table aliases).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can easily fix exception in your query by using `MAX()` aggregation on columns which are not in group by or adding them to the `group by`. 
I totally agree with @GMB about explicit joins and also would like to add that you can eliminate cross join and `employee` table extra scan using analytic `count()`:

```
SELECT
    d.dept_name,
    de.dept_no,
    e.gender,
    count(*)/max(e.total_cnt)  as Sex
FROM 
    (select emp_no, gender, 
            count(*) over() as total_cnt
       from employees e ) e
    INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON de.emp_no =  e.emp_no
    INNER JOIN departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no
GROUP BY 
    de.dept_no, 
    d.dept_name,
    e.gender
ORDER BY 
    de.dept_no;
```